# Insert current filename in vim command not working

Tags: vim

I want to execute my current file with a command specified in a makefile. To execute the makefile in a different t-mux pane I use [vimux](https://github.com/benmills/vimux). Why is this command not working:

```
:VimuxRunCommand("make run FILE=%")
```

It does not expand the `%` symbol and sends exactly `make run FILE=%` to the other pane. Why is it not expanding to the current file?

Comment: You need to use the `expand` function: `VimuxRunCommand("make run FILE=" . expand("%"))`

Comment: @L3viathan correct, except that it should be a dot instead of a plus operator

Comment: Thank you, it worked with the dot operator!